# Alfresco user language

Tags: alfresco

When I (Dutch) participate in a workflow with a Portugese colleague, he receives  task emails in Dutch (because my browser language is dutch), and I receive task emails in Portugese (because my colleague has his browser language in Portugese). This is because Alfresco sends emails in the language of the logged in user, instead of the recipients language.

I would like to program in the opposite behaviour, but I can not rely on the browser language for this.

Is there a way that Alfresco keeps (persistent) track of what language a user was last using?

Comment: I know there was a feature request for this back in the days of Alfresco 4.x, but I'm not sure if it ever got implemented....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is quite possible in the following way:

1. Save the browser language in the user profile (up on login)
2. Overwrite (spring overwrite) the MailActionExecuter Action and retrieve the user from the **TO** address and get the language and use that for the **Locale** or default to English

Comment: Hi Tahir, For step one, do you mean saving the language in the person node properties? Should I add a custom aspect for this, or is there already something available?

Comment: Hi Stefan, there is already an aspect available called sys:localized it's in the systemModel.xml